# How do I create a custom object class that's available to my methods in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I'm a huge fan of angular but it's got some tricky concepts with extremely nuanced differences between them and this is one of them.

I just want to create an class that I can use to create custom objects in my Angular controllers and factories. It surely shouldn't be that hard but I can't figure out how to do it. I want to have a custom, ResultSet class which I can instantiate to create instances of ResultSet. However for the life of me I can't figure out the correct syntax of factory v. service to use.

This is *all* I want:

```
ResultSet = function(dataSet){ 
  this.filter = function(){ 
    # filters and returns dataSet
    # ...
  }
}
```

and then I want to be able instantiate an instance of ResultSet inside a controller etc:

```
MyApp.controller('pageCtrl', ['ResultSet',  (ResultSet) ->
  # ...
  rs = ResultSet.new(dataToFilter)
```

### How can I create a service that allows me to create instances of my custom object?

It seems more correct to use an Angular Service rather than a Factory since a service returns an instance of an object (which is exactly what I want). But I can't figure out how to do this...

How would I use a service to declare my custom `ResultSet` class and then how would I instantiate an instance from it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
myApp.factory('ResulSet', function() {
    function ResultSetInstance(dataSet) { 
        this.filter = function(){ 
            // ...
        }
    }

    return {
        createNew: function(dataSet) {
            return new ResultSetInstance(dataSet);
        }
    };
});
```

and then

```
myApp.controller('pageCtrl', function(ResultSet) {
    var someData = ...;
    var rs = ResultSet.createNew(someData);
}
```

---

### Edit (from the question asker)

On experimenting with this further I found that you didn't even need to have the `createNew` method.

```
myApp.factory('ResultSetClass', function() {
    ResultSetClass = function(dataSet) { 
        this.filter = function(){ 
            // ...
        }
    }

    return ResultSetClass
});
```

works just fine and then you can call `new ResultSetClass(args)`.

#### Note for those using Coffeescript

Coffeescript will return the last variable or method in your class instance so if you are using coffeescript (as a general rule), it's imperative to return `this` at the end of the class definition

```
myApp.factory 'ResultSetClass', () ->
  ResultSetClass = (dataset) ->
    this.filter = () ->
      # do some stuff
    return this

  return ResultSetClass
```

If you don't return `this` explicitly then you'll find that when you call

```
myApp.factory 'ResultSetClass', () ->
  ResultSetClass = (dataset) ->
    this.filter = () ->
      # do some stuff
```

then you'll simply be left with the last thing the coffeescript returns which is the `filter` method.

Comment: Thank you and this works. I've got a question though - isn't the point of a service that it returns a new instance of an object - wouldn't a service be the correct route to take here?

Comment: This defines a service. A service is a singleton. This singleton has a single method createNew() allowing to create a new instances of ResultSetInstance. You could use service() instead of factory() to define the service, but the service would still be a singleton, and it would thus still have to provide a method creating new instances of ResultSetInstance.

Comment: eesh, ok. This is still a nuance deeper than I'm able to fully grok but I can see from this that you're right - ta! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15666048/service-vs-provider-vs-factory

Answer (score 14):

Maybe you were looking for something like this:

```
.factory('User', function (Organisation) {

  /**
   * Constructor, with class name
   */
  function User(firstName, lastName, role, organisation) {
    // Public properties, assigned to the instance ('this')
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.role = role;
    this.organisation = organisation;
  }

  /**
   * Public method, assigned to prototype
   */
  User.prototype.getFullName = function () {
    return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName;
  };

  /**
   * Private property
   */
  var possibleRoles = ['admin', 'editor', 'guest'];

  /**
   * Private function
   */
  function checkRole(role) {
    return possibleRoles.indexOf(role) !== -1;
  }    

  /**
   * Static property
   * Using copy to prevent modifications to private property
   */
  User.possibleRoles = angular.copy(possibleRoles);

  /**
   * Static method, assigned to class
   * Instance ('this') is not available in static context
   */
  User.build = function (data) {
    if (!checkRole(data.role)) {
      return;
    }
    return new User(
      data.first_name,
      data.last_name,
      data.role,
      Organisation.build(data.organisation) // another model
    );
  };

  /**
   * Return the constructor function
   */
  return User;
})
```

From [this](https://medium.com/opinionated-angularjs/angular-model-objects-with-javascript-classes-2e6a067c73bc) post by [Gert Hengeveld](https://medium.com/@ghengeveld).

Comment: How would you access a `self`/`this` variable inside a local function, for example, `checkRole()`? Or would that function have to be part of the User prototype?

Comment: Does "this" not work? Maybe "User", sorry I'm using typescript now so its a little different.

Answer (score 0):

I recently has do do something like that because I wanted to implement a factory of class instance, and being able to configurate my instances and benefit from Angular Dependency injection. I ended up with something like that

```
// Implem
export class XAPIService {
  private path: string;
  /* this DO NOT use angular injection, this is done in the factory below */
  constructor(
    private seed: XAPISeed,
    private $http: ng.IHttpService,
    private slugService: SlugService
  ) {
    const PATH_MAP: Map<Y, Z> = new Map([
      ['x', id => `/x/${id}`],
      ['y', id => `/y/${id}`],
    ]);
    this.path = PATH_MAP.get(this.seed.type)(this.seed.id);
  }

  list() {
    /* implem that use configured path */
    return this.slugService
    .from(this.path + `/x`)
    .then(url => this.$http.get<IX>(url))
    .then(response => response.data)
  }
}

export type IXAPIFactory = (s: XAPISeed) => XAPIService;
export function XAPIFactory(
  $http: ng.IHttpService,
  myService: SlugService
) {
  'ngInject';
  return (seed: XAPISeed) =>
    new XAPIService(seed, $http, myService);
}

// angular 

angular.module('xxx', [])
  .factory('xAPIFactory', XAPIFactory)

// usage in code 

export class XsController implements ng.IComponentController {
  /* @ngInject */
  constructor(
    private xAPIFactory: IXAPIFactory,
  ) {}

  $onInit() {
    this.xService = this.xAPIFactory({ id: 'aaabbbaaabbb', type: 'y' });
    return this.xService.list()
      .then(xs => {
        this.xs = xs;
      })
  }  
}
```